# How can I solve DiskPart has encountered an error: Data error (cyclic redundancy check)?

Tags: ssd, window, format, diskpart, redundancy

I was trying to clean up my SSD through the command prompt and installed the window. However, I could not clean the SSD and it showed Data error (cyclic redundacy check) - image below? Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Is there something wrong wiht my SSD? Thanks in advance for any helps.

[image]

Update:
I did the surface scan and found out there were many bad sectors in my SSD (image below). I did not have a chance to look into the system log event; however, my SSD is still under warranty. As a result, I decide to have the SSD replaced.

[image]

Comment: It says "see the System Event Log for more information". What is in the log then?

Comment: What do you mean by "installed the window?" Install Windows operating system?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It seems like my SSD has a bad sector thus I neither partition the disk nor cleaning the drive.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Yes, installing the Window OS.

Comment: "my SSD has a bad sector" – For now it's your guess. Please [edit] the question and post the exact log message(s) or whatever that led you to this conclusion. I'm not saying your conclusion is wrong, it may be right. But this is a technical site and hard data is preferred. Your interpretation of the data ("it seems like") is welcome, but only as an add-on. I've seen cases where askers were misinterpreting some data; revealing the exact data helped. In general log messages themselves may be misleading; experienced users may be able to spot such pitfalls. So what is in the log *exactly*?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thank you for your suggestion. I am not a computer person so I was 
 advised by my colleagues to do the surface scan on SSD and we found the bad sectors on it. Because the SSD is still under warranty, I requested a replacement. The post is updated.